# TreeView add Shell Icons

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, treeview, icons

I already created treeview where I can add some items. Basicly I want to tree-view all directories and files with icons associated to them.
So I have these functions:

1. Adding items to treeview

   ```
   HTREEITEM AddItemToTree(HWND hwndTree, char *text, int nLevel)
   {
       TVINSERTSTRUCT tvins;
       static HTREEITEM hPrev = (HTREEITEM)TVI_FIRST;
       static HTREEITEM hRootItem = NULL;
       static HTREEITEM hPrevLev2Item = NULL;
       AddIconToTree(hwndTree, text); //////////// THIS IS THE FUNCTION BELOW...
       tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE | TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
       tvi.iImage = 0;
       tvi.iSelectedImage = 0;
       tvi.pszText = GetFileNameFromPath(text);
       tvins.hInsertAfter = hPrev;
       tvins.item = tvi;

       if(nLevel == 1)
       {
           tvins.hParent = TVI_ROOT;
       }
       else if(nLevel == 2)
       {
           tvins.hParent = hRootItem;
       }
       else
       {
           TVITEM tviSetup;
           tviSetup.hItem = hPrev;
           tviSetup.mask = TVIF_PARAM;
           TVITEM * tviLocal = &tviSetup;
           TreeView_GetItem(hwndTree, tviLocal);

           if(nLevel > tviLocal->lParam)
           {
               tvins.hParent = hPrev;
           }
           else
           {
               HTREEITEM hPrevLocal = TreeView_GetParent(hwndTree, hPrev);
               tviLocal->hItem = hPrevLocal;
               TreeView_GetItem(hwndTree, tviLocal);
               for(int i = nLevel; i <= tviLocal->lParam;)
               {
                   HTREEITEM hPrevLocalTemp = TreeView_GetParent(hwndTree, hPrevLocal);
                   hPrevLocal = hPrevLocalTemp;
                   tviLocal->hItem = hPrevLocal;
                   TreeView_GetItem(hwndTree, tviLocal);
               }
               tviLocal->mask = TVIF_TEXT;
               TreeView_GetItem(hwndTree, tviLocal);
               tvins.hParent = hPrevLocal;

           }
       }

       hPrev = (HTREEITEM)SendMessage(hwndTree, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTVINSERTSTRUCT)&tvins);

       if(hPrev == 0)
       {
           return false;
       }
       if(nLevel == 1)
       {
           hRootItem = hPrev;
       }

       return hPrev;
   }
   ```
2. ADDING ICONS TO TREEVIEW:

   ```
   int AddIconToTree(HWND hwndTree, char *strPath)
   {
       SHFILEINFO sfi;
       memset(&sfi, 0, sizeof(sfi));
       SHGetFileInfo(strPath, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_SMALLICON);
       int index = sfi.iIcon;

       ICONINFO iconinfo;
       GetIconInfo(sfi.hIcon, &iconinfo);
       HBITMAP hBitmap = iconinfo.hbmColor;
       DestroyIcon(sfi.hIcon);

       himg = ImageList_Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR32, 1, 1);
       int iImageList = ImageList_Add(himg, hBitmap, NULL);
       DeleteObject(hBitmap);

       //TreeView_SetImageList(hwndTree, himg, TVSIL_NORMAL);
       SendMessage(hwndTree, TVM_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM)TVSIL_NORMAL, (LPARAM)(HIMAGELIST)himg);
       MessageBox(hwnd, strPath, "Path:", MB_OK); /* Because of this msgbox I found out what is
       really happening, because without it everything I have seen when I run the program was
       treeview with icon of the last file, which was folder...So blank icon.*/
       return index;
   }
   ```

My main problem is, that when I'm setting some icon, it is set not only for the one item as I'm expecting, but on all items in treeview. So basicly every item's icon is overwritten by new item's icon. By the way I know that if I want to get icon of folder, I need to use `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`...
So that's it. 
Any help would be greatly appriciated!
Thank You in advance :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `AddIconToTree` function you're creating a brand new image list every time, which will only ever have one icon in it. You need to maintain the same image list and add additional icons to it rather than re-creating it for every item.

Alternatively, you can get a handle to the shell imagelist with the [`SHGetImageList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185(v=vs.85).aspx) function and then assign it to the tree directly. If you don't need to add any of your own images to the tree's image list this is a much easier way of displaying system icons for files and folders as the shell imagelist handles all that for you.

```
// To initialise the tree's image list - do this one time only
HIMAGELIST himg;
if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetImageList(SHIL_SMALL, IID_IImageList, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&himg))))
    SendMessage(hwndTree, TVM_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM)TVSIL_NORMAL, (LPARAM)himg);
```

Then your `AddIconToTree` function simply becomes:

```
int AddIconToTree(HWND hwndTree, char *strPath)
{
    SHFILEINFO sfi;
    memset(&sfi, 0, sizeof(sfi));

    // SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX will return the icon's index within the shell image list
    SHGetFileInfo(strPath, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &sfi, sizeof(sfi),
        SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES);
    return sfi.iIcon;
}
```

And when you actually add items to the list, make sure you assign the index to the item:

```
tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE | TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
tvi.iImage = tvi.iSelectedImage = AddIconToTree(hwndTree, text);
```

Comment: Thank You for a quick response!
Well I already tried something with `SHGetImageList `, but not very successfuly. Using that I didn't see any icons at all.

Comment: Man, You deserve a huge golden Medal! It works! Thank You very much! Really appreciate it :) Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to vote up, but at least I can mark Your answer as solution :) And thank You again!